# Simplicity of the first Laplace-Beltrami eigenvalue on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, eigenvalues

On a compact Riemannian manifold $M$ (we assume Dirichlet boundary condition if $\partial M \neq \emptyset$), the Laplace-Beltrami operator $-\Delta$ has a discrete spectrum $0 < \lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 < .....$ going to $\infty$. Consider the eigenspace corresponding to the first eigenvalue $\lambda_1$. My question is, what is the dimension of this eigenspace?

It seems that the answer should be one, and the  otherwise one can locate two nodal domains corresponding to one of the first eigenfunctions, and then $\lambda_1$ is the first eigenvalue of each of these nodal domains, which should violate domain monotonicity.

On the other hand, suppose we are given one (even non-sign-changing) eigenfunction $\varphi$ corresponding to $\lambda$. Suppose the manifold $M$ is such that it has a non-trivial isometry $T$. Then $T\varphi (x) := \varphi (Tx)$ is also an eigenfunction, but in general one does not expect that $T\varphi = \varphi$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The multiplicity can be larger than 1, as shown by the [Bolza surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolza_surface).

Comment: @Bullet51 But the result seems correct for domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$, right? For example, see Evans' book on PDE, page 336. What goes wrong if one tries to repeat this proof for manifolds?

Comment: @Bullet51 By domain monotonicity, I meant that since the eigenvalues are defined variationally by Raleigh quotients, if you have two domains $\Omega_1 \subsetneq \Omega_2$, then $\lambda_1(\Omega_1) \geq \lambda_1(\Omega_2)$ simple because $H^1_0(\Omega_1) \subsetneq H^1_0(\Omega_2)$.

Comment: Is there a kind of domain monotonicity which assures strict inequality?

Comment: Suppose strict inequality does not hold. Then you can find $\Omega_1 \subsetneq \Omega_2$ such that they both have the same $\lambda_1$. Now, take the first Dirichlet eigenfunction on $\Omega_1$, and extend it by $0$ to $\Omega_2$. This is now a first eigenfunction for $\Omega_2$ which vanishes on an open set. Does this violate unique continuation?

Comment: No, as the new eigenfunction is not analytic.

Comment: But it solves an elliptic PDE with real analytic coefficients. If the boundary of the domains are also real analytic, is the solution not real analytic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly one needs to assume that $M$ is connected (otherwise the first eigenvalue is not necessarily simple). Then indeed the first eigenvalue is simple, the corresponding eigenfunction has a constant sign and if $M$ admits an isometry, so does this eigenfunction.

The proof is standard variational: the first eigenfunction delivers a minimum to
$\int |\nabla u|^2 \,dx $ under Dirichlet b.c. under assumption $\int u^2\,dx=1$. Then $v=|u|$ delivers the same minimum and thus is also an eigenfunction. But this cannot happen unless $v>0$ in $M\setminus \partial M$. Then $u$ must have a constant sign (we use that $M$ is connected), say $u>0$.

Then, if $\lambda_1$ is not simple, there is another eigenfunction $w$ which is orthogonal to $u$, but this is impossible since $w$ also has a constant sign.

Comment: But, in the simple case of a circle $S^1$, let's say parametrized by $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ with the endpoints identified, both $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ seem to be first eigenfunctions. Is this incorrect?

Comment: in the case of $\mathbb{S}^1$ the first eigenfunction is a constant, and the first eigenvalue is $0$

Comment: But it seems that $λ_1$ is used to denote the first eigenvalue greater that $0$.

Comment: $0$ is an eigenvalue only if $M$ is closed. Then the next eigenvalue could be of any chosen multiplicity, but nobody would call it "the first eigenvalue".

Comment: But the result seems correct for domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Dirichlet boundary condition, right? For example, see Evans' book on PDE, page 336. What goes wrong if one tries to repeat this proof for manifolds with boundary with the Dirichlet boundary condition?

Comment: Also, suppose $\varphi$ is an eigenfunction corresponding to $\lambda_1$, and $\varphi$ has $4$ nodal domains, say. Then $\lambda_1$ is also the first (non-zero) Dirichlet eigenvalue of all of these nodal domains. Does this not violate domain monotonicity?

Comment: user144878, there is nothing wrong to repeat it for manifolds, I gave you a proof. And the first eigenfunction has just one nodal domain, while $n$-th eigenfunction can have any number $m$ of nodal domains, $2\le m\le n$. See f.e. Courant & Hilbert

Comment: @VictorIvrii You said the first non-zero eigenvalue on a manifold without boundary could be of any chosen multiplicity. But we also know that on a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions, the first Dirichlet eigenvalue is simple, which is the same proof you gave above. Now suppose we consider a cylinder $\mathbb{S}^1 \times [0, 1]$. The first non-zero eigenvalue of this has multiplicity $2$. So something is going wrong here that is fine for domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @user144878, please read carefully: I am talking about the first, the smallest, eigenvalue, be it $0$ or not. This is a standard convention in the spectral theory. The $n$-th eigenvalue obviously is not the fits since $n\ge 2$

Comment: Professor Ivrii, thanks for   your answers, and I agree with what you are saying. But I have a question about the first non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of a manifold with boundary with Dirichlet boundary conditions. It is known that for a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with Dirichlet boundary conditions), this eigenvalue is also simple. But as soon as we move to a manifold with boundary that is not a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for example, $\mathbb{S}^1 \times [0, 1]$, the simplicity of the first non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ does not hold any more. I was trying to understand what goes wrong here.

Comment: If $\partial M=\emptyset$ then $0=\lambda_1 < \lambda_2\le \lambda_3\le \ldots$. The same is true for Neumann  b.c. even if $\partial M\ne \emptyset$. There are plenty of self-adjoint operators in math and applications, many of them have only point spectrum (or at least near the bottom), but the lowest eigenvalue is not necessarily even non–negative. Your confusion is the consequence of bad notations.